# Airflow get stuck and never finish on running PapermillOperator

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, airflow, openshift, papermill

I'm trying to run a DAG that have a task that is running a jupyter notebook.
Every task is doing well until it get's to Papermill operator.
the progress bar stay on 0 and the task never finish.
when looking inside the pod there is an:

```
AirflowException : "Celery command failed on host <airflow-worker id>"
i'm using airflow 2.3.3 and the pod have papermill(2.4.0) and ipykernel(6.15.2) installed
Arflow is running on openshift
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to give more ressources (cpu and memory) to the pod.

inside your dag:

```
from kubernetes.client import models as k8s

task_ressource = k8s.V1ResourceRequirements(limits={"cpu": "800m", "memory": "5Gi"}, request={"cpu": "200m", "memory": "2Gi"})
task = KubernetesPodOperator('task_id'='task_id',image='your image',resources=task_ressource)
```

Comment: it's seems that the pod didn't have enought memory to finish the task and get stuck